# What are the sizes of each primitive datatype on a Metro M4 Express SAMD51?

Tags: c++, data-type

What are the data sizes of all the primitive datatypes on a Metro M4 Express SAMD51 C++ implementation? In some C++ implementations, `int` has 16 bits and in other implementations it has 32 bits. Is

Comment: It depends on compiler's data model for target processor. But I'd rather use int16_t/int32_t instead. It's much better for portability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And that is the only difference in fundamental type sizes. On 8-bit Arduinos `int` is 16 bit and on 32-bit `int` is 32 bit.

- `short` is 16 bit
- `long` is 32 bit
- `long long` is 64 bit

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch to quickly find out **unsigned** maximum values on any architecture and deduce the bit width from them (I had to use sprintf, because Serial.println(unsigned long long) did not work on my Due):

```
#include <limits.h>

#define sprintfln(args...) { char _qsx6_[200]; snprintf(_qsx6_, 200, args); Serial.println(_qsx6_); } // _qsx6_ may collide with local var

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    unsigned char  uc = 0; uc=~uc; Serial.println(uc);
    unsigned short us = 0; us=~us; Serial.println(us);
    unsigned int   ui = 0; ui=~ui; Serial.println(ui);
    unsigned long  ul = 0UL; ul=~ul; Serial.println(ul);
    unsigned long long ull = 0ULL; ull=~ull; // doesn't work: Serial.println(~ull);
    
    sprintfln("char:%u short:%u int:%u long:%lu long long:%llu", uc, us, ui, ul, ull);
    sprintfln("char:%u short:%u int:%u long:%lu long long:%llu", UCHAR_MAX, USHRT_MAX, UINT_MAX, ULONG_MAX, ULLONG_MAX);
    sprintfln("char:%u short:%u int:%u long:%u long long:%u", sizeof(uc), sizeof(us), sizeof(ui), sizeof(ul), sizeof(ull));
    sprintfln("pointer:%u", sizeof(&uc));
}
```

On Arduino Due this gives (I expect it to be the same on SAMD51):

```
char:255 
short:65535 
int:4294967295 
long:4294967295 
long long:18446744073709551615
char:1 short:2 int:4 long:4 long long:8
pointer:4
```

Usually you could include "limits.h", but it seems that unsigned long long is missing (at least on Due). Hmmm, I didn't expect int and long to be the same, good to know.

Comment: 1. Note that `unsigned int ui = -1;` is a valid way to set an unsigned number to it's maximum value. 2. `sizeof(int)` may be more convenient. 3. `int` and `long` are both 32 bits on most 32-bit environments, and even on 64-bit Windows. 4. It would be cool to have also the size of pointers.

Comment: Oh, forgot about sizeof() which works on pointers, too. To your suggestion (1) I would comment that 'unsigned long long x = -1LL' is strange style with type conversion and its up to the compiler to do the right thing. I would not do that.